# Cronjobs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

Im Trying to create log file for every day using cronjobs. Whenever I restart Node server it create a new log file for the same otherwise it writes log in same file. Please help

Comment: Need more info, this is very vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a minute to read this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron
And this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

```
function startLogger() {
    var name = (require('moment')()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    var path = ('~/' + name);

    // ONLY if (path) doesn't exist, create it. (Do yourself the code)

    // Write to the end of the existent or created file:
    (require('fs')).appendFile(path, 'Your log line or multiple lines', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Log saved successfully!');
    });
}
```

PS: I do not recommend to use `require` inside `()`, I just did it because I'm without time but I hope you understand it and make your own code.